# ¿Como proteger rutas api en laravel 10 con breeze?

Tags: php, laravel

Eh estado trasteando un poco con breeze, laravel y un poco de spatie entonces en web.php cree la siguientes ruta

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:Administrador'])->group(function () {
    //rutas dashboard
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);
});
```

Donde puedo ingresar solo si eh iniciado sesion con rol administrador hasta ahi todo bien.
El problema que quize replicar la misma estructura en las rutas api.php
Asi que para ello no hice mas que copiar el codigo y meter ahi la ruta que quiero proteger

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'role:Administrador'])->group(function () {
     Route::get('/v1/get-users', [UsersController::class, 'getUsers']);
});
```

Pero la cosa es que no funciona simpre me redirige a otra pagina aunque haya iniciado sesion con el rol correspodiente de manera exitosa. Alternativamente probe con santum y creando un middleware personalizado.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RedirectIfAuthenticatedApi
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson() && Auth::check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'auth.api', 'role:Administrador'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/v1/get-users', [UsersController::class, 'getUsers']);
});
```

Pero todo sigue igual al entrar a las rutas que estan en api.php no me lo permite y siempre redirige a otra pagina. ¿Como podría solucionar esto?